# How to associate two different classes?

Tags: python, class

I'm building out a credit card charging/billing app that should charge/credit against cc accounts. I'd like to get some feedback on how I'm structuring things.

So far I have a as a parent class `Card`, with classes that inherent from `Card`:

```
Card:
- Credit Card
    constructor:
    - number
    - balance
    methods:
    - verify_cc
    - credit
    - charge

- Debit Card
    (mostly same as above)
```

It makes sense to me that Credit Card and Debit Card should inherit from Card in case I need to make things extensible, but so far I have nothing to inherit, so I'm not sure. Numbers and balance are unique to each card, so IMO they shouldn't be inherited. As of now, debit card is not required, but I'm just trying to structure my code such that in the event it becomes necessary, I won't have to re-write everything.

Next is:

```
User:
    constructor:
    - name
    - address
    methods:
    -add_user
```

This is the part I'm most uncertain about. How do I associate users with their credit card accounts?

Comment: I'm all for keeping things simple.  I'd like to suggest that perhaps Credit | Debit are just *types* of Card, and perhaps do not warrant inheritance, just a `card_type` field.  If this were a database, the `Card` would have an `id` and *maybe* an `owner_id`.  Whereas `User` would have a list of `Card.id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a generic `Card` class the inherit from that.

```
Card:
    constructor:
    - number
    - owner
    - co_owner
    methods:
    - credit
    - charge

- Debit Card (Card)
    methods:
    - available

- Credit Card (Card)
    constructor:
    - balance
    methods:
    - available
    - verify_cc
```

And you can use a list to associate cards to users.

```
User:
    constructor:
    - name
    - address
    - cards (list)
    methods:
    - add_card
    - remove_card
```

The same can be done with cards to track transactions.

Comment: Are the list of credit cards the CreditCard instances?

Comment: Also, why would a card not have a balance?

Comment: I was just trying to show how you could use inheritence, you can lay it out how you like. Different inplementations of balance may be a reason (but if that's the case then balance can be in Card then implement them differently in the subclasses

Answer (score 0):

> Numbers and balance are unique to each card, so IMO they shouldn't be inherited.

I think you are confusing inheritance with duplicating. When you inherit from a class, you inherit the attributes and methods. Suppose you have something like this

```
def CreditCard(Card):
    def __init__(number, balance):
```

You'll have to declare the number and balance when you instantiate a `CreditCard` class.

```
cc = CreditCard(xyz, abc)
```

These `xyz, abc` will become the number and balance of the variable cc.

On linking card with `User`, you can simply define an attribute in the class stores all the cards that a `User` has.

Something like

```
u = User()
u.cards
```

Answer (score 0):

I definitely recommend you to Google about OOP (object-oriented programming), but I can try to briefly introduce you to this concept. For example:

1) You can create a feature in User called "Cards" which stores all the cars the User has (it can be a dict or a list)

User:
    constructor:
    - name
    - address
    - cards

2) One option is that you can add cards to that feature by making it a parameter for User. Ex:

```
Me = User( name, address, cards)
```

2) Other option is that you can create methods for the user to manipulate that feature. Ex:

Methods:
- AddCard: add an instance of card to the User

```
name.AddCard(instanceOfCard)
```

- GetCard: gets an instance of card from the ones stored on the User

  name.GetCard(instanceOfCard)

There is a ton of articles on medium about OOP, here is one example of a funny one:
[How to explain object-oriented programming concepts to a 6-year-old[1](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/object-oriented-programming-concepts-21bb035f7260)